# Clarification about GetFieldID

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I was trying to build a native method and although it seems to run fine, but I am struggling to understand a field [*sig] in a function -

```
jfieldID GetFieldID(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
    const char *name, const char *sig);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html

For example I have a small Java code, which uses an instance variable called "i" and all this native method(named test) does is multiply this by 2.

Now I am referring to Java Complete Reference book - here the code goes like -

My question is - what is "I" in this -
    fid = (*env)->GetFieldId(env,cls,"i", "I");

When I read Oracle documenttion it says -
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html

> Accessing Fields of Objects
>   GetFieldID

```
    jfieldID GetFieldID(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, const char *name, const char *sig);
```

> Returns the field ID for an instance (nonstatic) field of a class. The field is specified by its name and signature. The GetField and SetField families of accessor functions use field IDs to retrieve object fields.
>   GetFieldID() causes an uninitialized class to be initialized.
>   GetFieldID() cannot be used to obtain the length field of an array. Use GetArrayLength() instead.
>   LINKAGE:
>   Index 94 in the JNIEnv interface function table.
>   PARAMETERS:
>   env: the JNI interface pointer.
>   clazz: a Java class object.
>   name: the field name in a 0-terminated modified UTF-8 string.
>   sig: the field signature in a 0-terminated modified UTF-8 string.

Could you please may be elaborate what is this field "sig"? I couldn't relate "I" with anything.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "NativeDemo.h"
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NativeDemo_test(JNIEnv *env , jobject obj)
{
    jclass cls;
    jfieldID fid;
    jint i;

    printf("Starting the native method\n");

    cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,obj);
    fid = (*env)->GetFieldId(env,cls,"i", "I");
```

Comment: A JNI method or field signature of this nature is what is output by the `javap -s` command for that method or field. Don't bother trying to figure them out for yourself when there is a tool that does it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please see the "employee" example below in Core Java, v. 2 ch. 12, by Horstmann and Cornell at http://www.horstmann.com/corejava.html
the "id" is the name of the field, here 
    private double salary;
inside the Employee class;  its signature ("sig"), or type, "D" (double) also must be specified. in your code, "I" is integer.
see the "Type Fields" at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html
once the jFieldId is obtained, it can be used to modify the value of the
field.

```
/**
  @version 1.10 1999-11-13
  @author Cay Horstmann
*/

#include "Employee.h"
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Employee_raiseSalary(JNIEnv* env, jobject     this_obj, jdouble byPercent)
{  
   /* get the class */
   jclass class_Employee = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, this_obj);

   /* get the field ID */
   jfieldID id_salary = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, class_Employee, "salary", "D");

   /* get the field value */
   jdouble salary = (*env)->GetDoubleField(env, this_obj, id_salary);

   salary *= 1 + byPercent / 100;

   /* set the field value */
   (*env)->SetDoubleField(env, this_obj, id_salary, salary);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question.

Answer (score 13):

"I" here is the signature of the primitive integer type. Oracle provides a table of type signatures: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp276

- Z boolean
- B byte
- C char
- S short
- I int
- J long
- F float
- D double

For non-primitive types, the signature is of form

- L *fully-qualified-class* ;

For arrays, [ is added.

For methods, () are used to separate parameters from the return value.

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question.

Comment: It’s irrelevant for fields, but `V` stands for `void`; `[` is prefixed, i.e. array of `int` is `[I` and for an example of a class, `Ljava/lang/String;` is one. The return value for functions is post-fix, i.e. a void function taking an int is `(I)V`.